# Can I use percentage of educated employees as an independent variable

Tags: regression

Can I use percentage of educated employees as an independent variable to measure productivity of firm in a multiple regression model

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is just a numerical variable with values between 0 and 100.

What is your doubt about its use?

Answer (score 1):

There are really two questions here:

1. Can you use a percentage value as an independent variable in a regression? Yes, you can. Of course, you still have to check the assumptions, but having a variable that is bounded by 0 and 100 does not violate any assumptions.
2. Will it measure productivity? Well .... Maybe sort of, depending on the industry. If it is, say, a construction company then % educated workers probably isn't going to be a good proxy for productivity. On the other hand, if it is (say) a firm that provides statistical consulting, then % educated might be useful as a proxy, but, even then, there are going to be a lot of complications.

Comment: thanks, I am testing impact of  human capital on labour productivity. labour productivity is output per worker and % of educated employees as a proxy of human capita.(manufacturing sector)